# PyCharm warning "End of statement expected" inside of type hints

Tags: python, pycharm, syntax-error, type-hinting

I'm getting this weird "End of statement expected" warning inside of a comment, which functions as a Python 2/3 type hint:

[image]

Any ideas, what is wrong with those type-hints and why I am getting this warning?

I am using PyCharm Professional 2018.2.3 with Python 3.6 (Anaconda).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but maybe Pycharm is unhappy with the import before the type comment? I think the general expectation (convention? standard?) is that the type comment comes first, before the docstring and any code, so it's possible whatever parser Pycharm is using may not be happy if you do it any other way. I also think your type hints for `compute_connected_components` is wrong -- you probably meant to do `# type: (blah) -> Tuple[a, b, c]` instead of `# type: (blah) -> (a, b, c)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) in your type hints with python >=3.5.

```
def resolve_notehead_wrt_staffline(notehead: 'CropObject', staffline_or_ledger_line: 'CropObject') -> int:
    """blahh blah"""
    from muscima.cropobject import CropObject
    ...
```

But even doing that won't fix the typehint in your case.  This is where I would suggest not doing imports from within a function.

edit: I stewed on this a bit and realized it's easy to simply say "*don't do that*" but without knowing why isn't very helpful.

[PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says you're not supposed to import anywhere but at the top of the file, but every once in a while we have a "very good reason" for doing it elsewhere.

*In your case*, the function is expecting the module to have already been imported otherwise the argument objects wouldn't exist.  With that being the case, you might as well put the import somewhere outside the scope of that function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately there are two things coming together here: I need to support Python 2, so I need type-comments and I would create a cyclic dependency if I import CropObject from the top of the class, so I guess I will just remove the type comment.
The thing is, that this used to work without warnings or errors, but has changed inside of PyCharm.

Comment: I think you're options are to either rewrite to remove the circular dependency or live without the typehint.  I don't know if there is another option in your specific case.